# Dynamically add multiple horizontal linearlayour to tab

Tags: java, android

I have a case where I need to add 2 TextViews to a horizontal LinearLayout, and replicate that structure numberous times.

For example:

|TextView1| |TextView2|
|TextView1| |TextView2|
etc..

The code I have so far is:

```
        public View createTabContent(String tag){
            LinearLayout mainTabLayout = new LinearLayout(Result.this);
            mainTabLayout.setOrientation(LinearLayout.HORIZONTAL);
            mainTabLayout.setLayoutParams(new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));

            for( Object param : mainHashMap.values() ){
                String key = param.toString();

                LinearLayout linLayout = new LinearLayout(Result.this);
                linLayout.setOrientation(LinearLayout.HORIZONTAL);

                linLayout.setLayoutParams(new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));

                TextView tvKey = new TextView(Result.this);
                tvKey.setText(key);
                tvKey.setTextSize(15);
                linLayout.addView(tvKey);
                try{
                    String member = this.transformMember(key);
                    Method method = mainClass.getMethod("get" + member);

                    TextView tvValue = new TextView(Result.this);
                    tvValue.setText((method.invoke(mainData) != null) ? method.invoke(dvlaData).toString() : "");
                    tvValue.setTextSize(10);
                    linLayout.addView(tvValue);
                } catch (InvocationTargetException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();  //To change body of catch statement use File | Settings | File Templates.
                } catch (NoSuchMethodException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();  //To change body of catch statement use File | Settings | File Templates.
                } catch (IllegalAccessException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();  //To change body of catch statement use File | Settings | File Templates.
                }
                Log.d("ResultActivity", "adding to view");
                mainTabLayout.addView(linLayout);
            }
            return mainTabLayout;
        }
```

Log.d shows that it is running over every item it needs to, however the TabContent only have the last LinearLayout displaying. It's overwriting the previous LinearLayouts added to the mainTabLayout.

I hope this makes sense...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try setting your mainTabLayout orientation to vertical instead of horizontal

Comment: Happens to all of us haha.